# "Core Data could not fulfill a fault for..."

Tags: ios, core-data, crash-reports, magicalrecord, crashlytics

My app is in App Store now. From 2 users I got a lot of crashes. I track them with Crashlytics. The screenshots from my issue are following:

[image]

[image]

> Core Data could not fulfill a fault for... WLWishlist

What does it mean? Is it sth wrong with `WLWishlist` or objects with relationships to `WLWishlist`?

Can you help me debug this?

Below is the line 82 for the file when the crash appeared:

[image]

Comment: What's the code at that line?

Comment: Can you write what line do you mean?

Comment: The one it mentions in the crash log.

Comment: @trojanfoe updated the question

Answer (score 0):

That `NSObjectInaccessibleException` should give you a clue, as should the `CoreData could not fulfill a fault for ... /WLWishlist/...`. Somewhere you create an instance of a `WLWishlist` which is an `NSManagedObject` subclass. You might be creating this instance directly or perhaps it is a related entity from some other managed object. This particular instance is a fault; it's properties have not yet been loaded from the persistent store but should be retrievable on demand. It is expected that your persistent store will be able to fulfill any fault and provide the values of that object's properties. In this case that was not possible and so the persistent store throws an exception.

One way this might happen is if you attempt to fulfill a fault for an object which has been deleted from the persistent store. Without knowing more about what your application is doing it's impossible to say how you got into this situation.

Comment: Simply... you suggest that I try to set relationships to object that was removed from persistent store, right? But you can confirm... it is not related to memory warning crashes, right?

Comment: And... There is no objects related to WLWishlist right, but they should be there. It may be this....